# OSLC Error - all-gen command Failed

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Working with Anywhere (7.5.2) Work Execution app. Recently migrated MAM and Anywhere to new server environment. After executing RDF PULLER,
build.cmd all-gen is failed with "ResAnywhereResource~null". how to resolve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had cleared the oslc-docs directory manually, you have lost a few resources that are not pulled by the rdf-puller but are shipped as part of our platform.  The ResAnywhereResource is one of these resources.

You could try running "build.cmd/sh update-platform" to replace these oslc-docs files from the platform package, then rerunning RDF-PULLER again to get the latest from your server.  As you know you only need to run the RDF-PULLER when you're changing the app to show additional attributes.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Working fine now.